# Scale only upright font in superscript math mode

Tags: fonts, scaling, mtpro

Is there a way to scale only the upright font (used in operators like sin, log) in superscript math mode?

I'm using Baskerville MT Pro as text font, with XeTeX and mathspec, and MathTime Pro 2 as math font, but, in superscript math mode, Baskerville becomes too small, compared to MathTime Pro 2.

**Note:**

I do not want to scale Baskerville completely, i.e. not only the upright in math superscript, or scale MT Pro.

Image:

[image: Operator font in superscript math mode becomes too small]

Thank you.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: My impression is that you want to scale the MathTime fonts down, rather than the converse.

Comment: No, I do not. I think MT Pro superscript font size is ideal for reading, so I only want to scale Baskerville in superscript math mode (please note: _only in superscript math mode_).

Answer (score 2):

Redefine the math font size:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{BaskervilleMTStd-Regular}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}
\setmathfont[range=\mathrm]{BaskervilleMTStd-Regular}
\makeatletter
\DeclareMathSizes{\@xipt}{11}{9}{8}%% Definition for 11pt 
%  display -- text -- script -- scriptscript
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\[ \int\frac{e^{\arcsin(\arccos x)}}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} \mathrm{d}x \]

BaskervilleMTStd-Regular

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I do not want to scale down MT Pro 2 superscript font size; I think it is ideal because it is readable. I, as said in the question, only want to scale up Baskerville in superscript math mode -- only in superscript math mode, but I don't know if there is a way to do that.